# Is it possible to mount a shared memory segment on a file-system using C or C++

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, shared-memory

I want to see if it is possible to mount a shared memory segment on Linux, to a file system.
Is that possible? But I don't know where to start.

Can someone throw any hints?

Comment: The statement "mount a shared memory segment on Linux, to a file system" does not compute. The closest thing to that would be mmap-ing a file into a process's address space, basically the opposite of what you described.

Comment: Could you describe more of what you want? Give some more details... Also, check this out: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand015.html